# libvirt access file inside VM from host

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt

Is it possible to use libvirt to access files inside VM from host machine? anyone has idea? 
thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use guestfs for that. You just need to stop the VM first.